# What accessories are needed when learning guitar?

Tags: electric-guitar

I'm an absolute beginner and I'm planning to buy a [Yamaha Pacifica 611HFM](http://www.bax-shop.nl/elektrische-gitaren/yamaha-pacifica-611hfm-elektrische-gitaar-zwart). At the moment I have no idea what else I need in order to start playing the guitar. Could anyone give some suggestions on gear I would need?

Comment: Your guitar doesn't matter. You want regular guitar accessories. *What in particular* depends hugely on your personal preferences, needs and dreams. Hence I don't think this question can be adequately answered, because it would need to list every possible guitar equipment necessary, and that could fill a magazine or perhaps even a small book; way too much for an SE answer.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Music.SE!  
You can click [here](http://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
to see our scope (what/what not to ask) and how to ask questions 
[here](http://music.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). This is a little bit like a guitar recommendation question which would be off-topic.

Comment: I think this question could have been edited and kept open.  It was not asking for specific equipment as in brand names, but rather a list of basic items one must have in order to embark on a journey of learning to play guitar.  Many beginning musicians are going to find their way to Music - SE in an effort to find guidance.

Comment: Where will you be practicing? In some cases, rather than an amplifier, I'd suggest getting a little multi-effect unit that you can use with headphones.

Comment: I will be practicing at home. In any case, I have already ordered for an amplifier. I guess I can control the volume so that my neighbors will not complain, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a few things you might want to get for an **electric guitar** in addition to what Jamie Brace listed.

- **A basic string winder** (around $2.00 US) to make it easier to change your strings when needed.
- **A guitar strap**.  I recommend a good one.  To learn more about why this is important read this - **[Playing Guitar Standing](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/30270/16897)**.  There are a few paragraphs in that answer that discuss why it is important to use a strap when playing an electric guitar (vs acoustic) either standing **or seated**.  There is also a paragraph about **what type of straps might work best** for most people.
- **A capo**.  As a beginning guitarist, you may find a capo very helpful for many reasons.  For an in depth discussion of how you might benefit from using a capo, read this - **[Why a beginning guitarist should have a capo](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/28950/16897)**
- **A Headphone Guitar Amplifier**.  You mentioned not wanting to disturb your neighbors while practicing.  You can certainly practice unplugged, but you will lose all the cool sounds that can be achieved from the electronics on your guitar.  If the amp you ordered does not have a headphone jack (many do), you might want to get a headphone guitar amplifier like this - **[Headphone Amplifier](http://www.musiciansfriend.com/amplifiers-effects/nady-axehead-mini-headphone-guitar-amp)**

Learning to play guitar is a lifelong journey.  Every day offers a new opportunity to improve your chops.  Enjoy your journey as you work towards becoming an increasingly more accomplished guitarist.

Answer (score 3):

I'll list some basics for you, but your best bet would be to find a guitar teacher who can explain everything in detail for you.

- a guitar
- an amplifier
- tuner (whether it's a pedal or a clip on, it's essential)
- picks (more than just 1, as many as possible of a size and thickness you prefer)
- 1/4" jack cable/s
- spare strings
- tutorials, lessons, teacher, anything you can use to start and improve